# Calling a different process when method chaining in PHP?

Tags: php, methods, domdocument, chaining

Firstly, sorry for my flawed english and being dumb :O

I just want to know any procedure to make this possible in method chaining. As per the DOMDocument class, the sequence of the characters are altered accordingly if we perform method chaining for example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$applicant = $dom->createElement('applicant');

$name = $dom->createElement('name');
$firstname = $dom->createElement('firstname', 'Joe');
$middlename = $dom->createElement('middlename', 'Johnson');
$lastname = $dom->createElement('lastname', 'Smith'); 

$dom->appendChild($applicant);
$applicant->appendChild($name);
    $name->appendChild($firstname);
    $name->appendChild($middlename);
$name->appendChild($lastname);
```

//OUTPUT

```
<applicant>
   <name>
      <firstname>Joe</firstname>
      <middlename>Johnson</middlename>
      <lastname>Smith</lastname>
   </name>
</applicant>
```

---

If I do

```
$dom->appendChild($applicant);
$applicant->appendChild($name);
        $name->appendChild($firstname)
             ->appendChild($middlename);
$name->appendChild($lastname);
```

//OUTPUT

```
<applicant>
   <name>
      <firstname>
           Joe
           <middlename>Johnson</middlename>
      </firstname>
           <lastname>Smith</lastname>
   </name>
</applicant>
```

--
How is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appendChild` returns the appended child, so your next `appendChild` acts on that return value.

So in your first example you're allways working on `$name` in the second twice on `$name` and once on `$firstname`.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php

Comment: If that is the case I think method chaining should have not been possible since an instance of the class ($this) was supposed to be returned. :/

Comment: @Rei Where does it state that `$this` is returned? The manual for `appendChild` shows that the newly appended child is returned. I hope you're not mixing this with how jQuery works?

Comment: No. I wasn't meant to say $this was was returned. According to what yes123 posted. A return value $this is needed in order to perform chain methods.

Comment: @Rei Ah! Yes, this would be correct. Which leaves you with the simple conclusion that you'll not be able to use chaining while working with php DOM* objects. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you meant.

Anyway chaining as you probabily know it's done like this:

```
public function method() {
  //> Code
  return $this;
}
```

If you need a methods that returns another kind of object it's done like this:

```
public function method() {
  //> Code
  return new ObjectOtherTypeWhatEver;
}
```

Of course you can return another instance of another object like this (what does `appendChild` methods):

```
public function method($object) {
  //> Code
  return $object;
}
```